# When magento Indexer call

Tags: indexer

I need to know that, When magento runs the indexer process on below phase.

```
      - Add to cart (While user add products on cart)
      - Add to wishlist (While user add products on wishlist)
      - Apply Coupon code
      - Submitting order
```

Your inputs are appreciable.

Comment: add to cart, add to wishlist, coupon etc do not invoke magento indexing as quote and order data is already stored in flat data format

Comment: to check further on magento indexes , you can refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4946724/857855

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indexes are triggered on the following events:

**Url Rewrite:**

- product save
- category save
- store save
- store group save
- config save
- product import

**Flat Category:**

- category save
- store save
- store group save

**Categories-products association**

- product save
- product mass action
- store save
- store group save
- product import

**Flat products**

- product save
- product mass action
- attribute save
- attribute delete
- store view save
- store view delete
- store group save
- product import

**Product prices**

- product save
- product delete
- product mass action
- config save
- product import
- customer group save

**Product attributes**

- product save
- product delete
- product mass action
- attribute save
- product import

**Tag aggregation**

- product save
- product delete
- product mass action
- tag save
- tag relation save

**Search**

- product save
- product delete
- product mass action
- attribute save
- attribute delete
- store view save
- store view delete
- store group save
- config save
- product import
- category save

**[EDIT]**
Every indexer model has a member var called `$_matchedEntities` that contain every action that can trigger a reindex. For example look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url`

Comment: do you got this by your experience?

Comment: @Manik experience and looking through the code. take for example the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url`. Look at the `$_matchedEntities` member and you will see the actions that (can) trigger a reindex. it's the same for all the indexer models. Maybe I should put that in the answer :)

Comment: Thanks Marius for explore the above question, it's really helpful for us...